# why the below boost variant visitor code doesnt work

Tags: c++, boost, boost-variant, apply-visitor

I have a struct A:

```
struct A
{
    //some implementation
}
```

My boost variants are:

```
boost::variant<double, A> v1 = 1.0;
boost::variant<double, A> v2 = 2.0;
```

My visitor functor is defined as:

```
class SomeWork:
    public boost::static_visitor<int>
{
public:
    
    int operator()(const A& data1, const A& data2) const
    {
        //some work
        return 1;
    }

    int operator()(const double& data1, const double& data2) const
    {
        //some work
        return 2;
    }

};
```

```
int main()
{
    boost::variant<double, A> v1 = 1.0;
    boost::variant<double, A> v2 = 2.0;

    boost::apply_visitor(SomeWork(), v1 ,v2);
    return 0;
};
```

When I do above I get an error saying:

```
error C2664: 'int SomeWork::operator ()(const A&, const A&) const': cannot convert argument 2 from 'T' to 'const double &'
```

Not sure why this happening.

boost version I am using is 107200

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens if the `variant`s hold `double`, `A`?  Or `A`, `double`?

Comment: @StephenNewell Hey - i get the same error

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/4d1jb88sx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`boost::apply_visitor` needs to consider every possible combination of types that your `variant` instances hold.  This means `SomeWork` is missing the following combinations:

```
    int operator()(const A& data1, const double& data2) const
    {
        //some work
        return 3;
    }

    int operator()(const double& data1, const A& data2) const
    {
        //some work
        return 4;
    }
```

When adding those, I'm able to compile your code.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/4d1jb88sx

Comment: I can't help but notice that by now we don't need a visitor at all https://godbolt.org/z/jeY54cjoY